# Compile VB code to exe

Tags: vb.net, compilation

I have txt file with some code in it. How to compile it to working exe? I tried `Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider.CompilerAssemblyFromFile` but it generates dll file

Comment: May be easier to compile with regular compiler from command line (vbc.exe, available on any machine with .Net Framework).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an .EXE from an .EXE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463073/create-an-exe-from-an-exe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VBC.exe
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/380cz5k4.aspx

If you need to do this from inside a program you may need to create a process and give it some arguments or use the Shell Function.